# Prisma: Error querying the database: db error: FATAL: too many connections

Tags: next.js, prisma

I am using Prisma as ORM in my nextjs app. I am initiating the Prisma client in a lib file and importing the same where ever i need the instance. But still am getting the following error.

> Error querying the database: db error: FATAL: too many connections for
> role "qcjoaamjgbnxjx"

prisma-client:

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();
export default prisma;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try instantiating `PrismaClient` as shown [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/support/help-articles/nextjs-prisma-client-dev-practices) so that a new connection isn't created on every reload.

Comment: So this was helpful, but I have a certain API endpoint that needs to run many queries. Whenever this endpoint is hit, the 20/20 connections gets maxed out. I'm not sure why though, as I created a global Prisma client. Do I need to just upgrade so I have many more than 20 connections? I feel that there must be some optimizing I can do, but I'm not sure exactly how.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error in  my local computer. but my error was due to I have opened too many panels in pgAdmin. my database is Postgres. after removing all panels. my issue is solved